# When i click on dataGridView it says index is out of range must be non negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: c#, winforms

here is my code

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        button2.Text = "Update";
        textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["dgProCode"].Value.ToString();
        textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["dgProName"].Value.ToString();
        textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["dgQuantity"].Value.ToString();
        dateTimePicker1.Text = DateTime.Parse(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["dgDate"].Value.ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["dgStatus"].Value.ToString() == "Active")
        {
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What's the DGVs selection mode? _"The SelectionMode property must be set to FullRowSelect or RowHeaderSelect for the SelectedRows property to be populated with selected rows."_

Answer (score 0):

You are not first checking to see if there are any selected rows when double-clicked. Check first before attempting to reference the first one...

```
if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows == null || dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == 0)
    return;

button2.Text = "Update";
textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["dgProCode"].Value.ToString();
textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["dgProName"].Value.ToString();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

just change datagrid propieties, Selection Mode to "FullRowSelect".